# MySQL MAX(id) called from PHP produces strange value

Tags: php, mysql

I am just trying to get the auto incremented value of a table that is currently the highest.  I do not need to know what the next auto increment is, just the highest value of what is in the table right now.  I am using the code below, but regardless of what the actual auto increment is, what table I last inserted into, what table was last updated /  modified, or any other factors that I can see, the value always returns `Resource id #4`.  This is perplexing to me for two reasons.  First I don't understand why the number is always `4`, second I do not understand why I am getting back a string value (with letters and a symbol) instead of just an integer.  **What is the deal here?**

`<?php $highest_id = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM customers"); ?>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`mysql_query` doesn't return the value from the query, it returns a result resource. To get the actual value, you need to use one of the `mysql_fetch_*` functions, passing it the result resource you got from `mysql_query`.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM customers");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $highest_id = $row[0];
?>
```

or the shorter...

```
<?php
    $highest_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM customers"), 0);
?>
```

Comment: I feel kind of stupid posting that up there, but yeah, I actually did have it like that at first, but the result returned was `''`.  I'll edit my post to show you what I tried at the very first (which is what you are suggesting).

Comment: Ok, i see what I did wrong now.  My original code I used `mysql_fetch_array` and then i messed up where you have the `0` in `$row[0]`.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

This is my answer:

```
require_once 'db_cconnection.php';
$query = "SELECT MAX(stud_id) FROM student_tbl";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,  $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

When you use `mysqli_fetch_row` it will fetch only one row, as we only want one row. `$row` will be an array. So we need to get its value through array index.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query` returns a result handle, not the actual result.  In other words, your query's result is saved as resource id #4 (and that's not guaranteed to be the same always, it's coincidence if you see it that way all the time).

To access the result you need to use something like [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or one of the other functions in the same family.

Something like this:

```
<?php 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(c_id) as max FROM customers"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$highest_id = $row['max'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$highest_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM customers"));
```

Comment: Very concise, but should be:

$highest_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM customers"), 0);

Answer (score 0):

the 2015 way of doing this
suppose you have database ($this->db)

```
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM `customers`')->fetchColumn();
```